# On k8s, Is ServiceBinding same with ServiceBindingRequest?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to use k8s ServiceBindingOperator, with ServiceBinding.
But I found there is ServiceBindingRequest which act as ServiceBinding on RedHat Article

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/12/19/introducing-the-service-binding-operator#

But I couln't find ServiceBindingRequest CRD on API:[apps.openshift.io/v1alpha1] from any sites,
only ServiceBinding could.

Where is ServiceBindingRequest CRD? or those two of them are same resource?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the Operator.

The article you referenced says that the Operator "has changed significantly" and links to [How to use service binding with RabbigMQ](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/11/03/how-use-service-binding-rabbitmq#about_the_example)

In that example, only `ServiceBinding` is described. I think you should continue to use `ServiceBinding` and use the updated article.

Comment: Oh... There is a info about that,,,, my mistake.. thx!!!

Comment: Good luck! I learned about that Operator from your question and it's interesting, thanks.